# Print from Mac OS X 10.5.8 to HPC3180 on Windows 7, How?

Tags: windows-7, macos, printing

Can anyone point to a document that describes how to print from a Mac OS X 10.5.8 to an HP Photosmart C3180 series print connected to Windows 7. I can’t get anything but nonsense to print. I was able to do this with Windows XP, could not do it with Vista and am now hoping to get it done with System 7. HP has been no help at all. Apparently nobody who works for them knows anything about both computers.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, you won't be able to get it to work...

From HP:

> OS supported Windows 98 SE, Windows
>   Me, Windows 2000 Professional with
>   Service Pack 3 (SP3) or higher,
>   Windows XP, Windows XP Media or Tablet
>   edition, Windows Vista
>
> Processor Windows 2000 and XP: Any
>   Intel Pentium II, Celeron, or
>   compatible processor (Pentium III or
>   higher recommended)
>
> Windows Vista: A modern 800 MHz 32-bit
>   (x86) or 64-bit (x64) Processor (1 GHz
>   or higher recommended)
>
> RAM   Windows 2000 and XP: 128 MB RAM
>   (256 MB or higher recommended)
>
> Windows Vista: 512 MB RAM (1 GB or
>   higher recommended)

The specifications make me believe that this is a "dumb" printer.  In otherwords, there is no significant processing power on the printer, it's all in the Windows driver.  (Your computer does all the processing needed for the printing)

Network printing, requires the client system to have the driver for the printer, and thus there is no Macintosh driver...  Thus your gibberish on the output.

Now, the only sensible option might be Gutenprint ( http://gutenprint.sourceforge.net).  They do have drivers created for *some* of the photosmart models...

```
HP PhotoSmart 7150  hp-psc_7150 HP-PhotoSmart_7150   
HP PhotoSmart 7345  hp-psc_7345 HP-PhotoSmart_7345   
HP PhotoSmart 7350  hp-psc_7350 HP-PhotoSmart_7350   
HP PhotoSmart 7550  hp-psc_7550 HP-PhotoSmart_7550   
HP PhotoSmart P100  hp-psc_p100 HP-PhotoSmart_P100   
HP PhotoSmart P1000 pcl-P1000   HP-PhotoSmart_P1000  
HP PhotoSmart P1100 pcl-P1100   HP-PhotoSmart_P1100  
HP PhotoSmart P1115 hp-psc_p1115    HP-PhotoSmart_P1115  
HP PhotoSmart P1215 hp-psc_p1215    HP-PhotoSmart_P1215  
HP PhotoSmart P1218 hp-psc_p1218    HP-PhotoSmart_P1218  
HP PhotoSmart P130  hp-psc_p130 HP-PhotoSmart_P130   
HP PhotoSmart P1315 hp-psc_p1315    HP-PhotoSmart_P1315  
HP PhotoSmart P230  hp-psc_p230 HP-PhotoSmart_P23
```

So one of those might give you a potentially workable driver...